# Find rows with maximum count which have multiple joins in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
firstname  lastname  quantity object no datecol
             
        
soman       mitra    50         1       31-05-2021
nitya      sharma    100        2        31-05-2021
tanisha    agarwal   200        3        31-05-2021
tarun      mittal    300        4       31-05-2021
```

Above is the output of multiple joined tables. Now, I want to find the rows which have the maximum  **quantity**
How can I do this since I have multiple table joined. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the row(s) having the maximum quantity, then use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES -- current select list
FROM                   -- current query
ORDER BY quantity DESC;
```

Comment: but i have to use this value in multiple joins? will it work

Comment: I have given the best answer of which I can think, given the very limited data you provided (a fragment of the output, no query, no table structure).  Include more information here for best results.

Comment: SELECT distinct a.firstname,b.objectno,c.lastname,d.quantity,e.datecol
FROM [dbo].[tbl1] as a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl2] as b ON a.firstname=b.firstname
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl3] AS c ON c.objectno=b.objectno and c.lastname=b.lastname
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl4] AS d on d.quantity=c.quantity
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl5] AS e on e.datecol=a.datecol
WHERE  datecolI='99991231'

Comment: this is my query

Comment: Yes, my answer should work then.  Just add `TOP 1 WITH TIES` to the select clause, and add the suggested `ORDER BY` clause at the end.

Comment: what is TIES? could you please tell

Comment: Please review the documentation on this.  It just means return all records sharing the max quantity.